# Multiple RegularExpression attribute in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

In my MVC 4 application I need to validate on account registration screen; password for containing at least 1 digit, 1 uppercase & 1 lowercase charater. I want to have model class property something like

```
[Display(Name = "Register_Password", ResourceType = typeof(VirtuOxAdmin))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(VirtuOxAdmin), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Register_PasswordRequired")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(VirtuOxAdmin), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Admin_CreateCustomer_PasswordMinLength")]
    [MaxLength(32, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(VirtuOxAdmin), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Admin_CreateCustomer_PasswordMaxLength")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(VirtuOxAdmin), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Admin_CreateCustomer_AtleastOneDigit")]
    [RegularExpression("[A-Z]+", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(VirtuOxAdmin), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Admin_CreateCustomer_AtleastOneUChar")]
    [RegularExpression("[a-z]+", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(VirtuOxAdmin), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Admin_CreateCustomer_AtleastOneLChar")]
    public string Password { set; get; }
```

But I am getting error Error  **Duplicate 'RegularExpression' attribute**

How can I code for password validation?

Answer (score 4):

You have to combine all the elements into a single regex. To do that, you can use zero-width look ahead assertions. Something like this should work:

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But by doing this way I could not show error message based on which validation fails.

Comment: Correct, you will have to use a more generic message like "The password must include a lowercase letter, an uppercase letter and a digit."

Comment: If that's not good enough, you will need to create a custom validator and write the code for it. Then you can test each regex separately and return the appropriate message. In my experience, that's usually not necessary.